# PDO statement fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get this statement to work but Im guessing there must be an error in it because it does not produce any results or errors at all. Can someone with more experience and fresh eyes look it over to see if I have something wrong. Code is below:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=timecard', 'username', 'password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `timeRecords` SET `jobDescription`= :jobDescription, `equipType`= :equipType, `unitNumber`= :unitNumber, `unitHours`= :unitHours) 
                            WHERE `employeeID`= :employeeID AND `date`= :dateToday');

    $stmt->execute(array(':employeeID' => $_SESSION['employeeID'], ':dateToday' => $dateToday, ':jobDescription' => $jobDescription,
                         ':equipType' => $equipType, ':unitNumber' => $unitNumber, ':unitHours' => $unitHours));
```

Comment: How do you know if it doesn't produce any errors?  I don't see any attempts at catching them.

Comment: Are you echoing anything out?

Comment: I'm guessing there is no entry where the `employeeID` and `date` will match the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Daedalus is right. Use the try/catch block to debug. Otherwise the `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` and `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` attributes are useless.

Comment: Found the error I left a `)` before the WHERE statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error found in the original code I left a `)` before `WHERE` it was found thanks to the suggestion to use the `try/catch block` updated and working code below:

```
try{
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=timecard', 'username', 'password');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `timeRecords` SET `jobDescription`= :jobDescription, `equipType`= :equipType, `unitNumber`= :unitNumber, `unitHours`= :unitHours 
                        WHERE `employeeID`= :employeeID AND `date`= :dateToday');

$stmt->execute(array(':employeeID' => $_SESSION['employeeID'], ':dateToday' => $dateToday, ':jobDescription' => $jobDescription,
                     ':equipType' => $equipType, ':unitNumber' => $unitNumber, ':unitHours' => $unitHours));
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad you found your solution with `try`.

Might I also add that it is very helpful to add standard error reporting when coding your site. As you work on a script, add this to the top:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
?>
```

And remove it before you make the page live. This has saved me from hundreds of errors.

You can even take it a step further and turn on error reporting for your IP address (assuming your IP is static). It is generally a bad practice to leave an IP allow/restrict going so you should remove it when you are done editing.

```
//Change to match your IP address
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="123.456.78.9"){
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
}
```